# Using propositional logic to show logical equivalence of $\neg (q \to p) \lor (p \land q) \equiv q$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trouble to figure out the how to prove the logical equivalence between these two propositions.

I have gotten to where I denote $A := \neg (q \to p) \lor (p \land q)$.

And from $A$ I thought about using the conditional identity where $\neg(\neg q \lor p)$. But after that I'm stuck. If anyone could provide insight that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: What rules are you allowed to use?

Comment: Idempotent laws: 
Associative laws: 
Commutative laws: 
Distributive laws
Identity laws: 
Domination laws: 
Double negation law: 
Complement laws: 
De Morgan's laws
Absorption laws
Conditional identities:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may write
$$
\begin{align}
A &= (¬(q → p)) ∨ (p ∧ q)
\\\\&=(¬(¬q ∨ p)) ∨ (p ∧ q)
\\\\&=(¬(¬q)∧ (¬p)) ∨ (p ∧ q)
\\\\&=(q∧ (¬p)) ∨ (q ∧ p)
\\\\&=q∧ (¬p∨ p)
\\\\&=q∧ 1
\\\\&=q.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Hi @olivier oloa I am trying to go down your list of proof. And please correct me if I'm wrong, but we first start off with the definition, then use the conditional law, then use De Morgan's law, then Double Negation Law, then Associative Law. But what law is it where the negation of p or p is equal to one? Thank you!

Comment: Edit: Nevermind I think I understand what you did. Sorry I am not familiar with the use of 1, but because the negation of p and p is always true it is a tautology meaning we can write that using T. Then using the idempotent law q  and q is just q. :)

Comment: @Sandra Bae Hoping it's Ok now.

Comment: @SandraBae When I write +2, I believe you a full understanding of a concept.  When I write +1, you have some understanding, but there's more in the study of logic.  When I write -1, I believe you had the wrong name of a law, but I could easily be wrong on some point, since I haven't seen your text.  Olivier started with the definition (+2), used a conditional law (+1), a De Morgan's law (+1) (maybe this should be a +2, I'm not sure), a double negation law (+2), a distribution law (-1), it's the (negation of p) OR p is always true, and I do not believe any idempotent law got used (-1).